# MYSQL SELECT returns timestamp with timezone calculation

Tags: mysql

I have a TIMESTAMP field in my table.

When I insert a new row with a timestamp value, the value is saved correctly. but when I'm making a SELECT request (via sequelize), I get the timestamps formatted to -2 hours (the difference from my timezone and the UTC timezone)

is there a way to force the SQL to always return the UTC timezone?

Comment: SQL returns in UTC format only. Check the client you are using to run the query. There must be a setting in the client to disbale this featue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
>   storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
>   (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default,
>   the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The
>   time zone can be set on a per-connection basis.

So the reason you get the time difference when you retrieve is because MySQL converts it to your server's time upon retrieval.

From the documentation again:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

> The initial global server time zone value can be specified explicitly
>   at startup with the --default-time-zone option on the command line, or
>   you can use the following line in an option file:
>
> `default-time-zone='timezone'`
>
> If you have the SUPER privilege, you can set the global server time
>   zone value at runtime with this statement:
>
> `SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;`

So if you want to change your MySql's server timezone to UTC you should use:

In my.ini file (restart needed)

```
default-time-zone = '+00:00'
```

Runtime

(If you want to set the timezone per connection just ommit GLOBAL)

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+00:00';
```